# Error installing Karma with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

I try install Karma with command line: npm install karma and always receive the same error:

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: anymatch@'^1.1.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.2.0","1.0.0","1.1.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:709:10)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:631:10
npm ERR!     at saved (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
 "install" "karma"
npm ERR! cwd C:\users\jose
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.24
```

As you can see I am using NodeJS x64 v0.10.9 and npm v1.2.24. I tried with x86 versions with no result.

Comment: Looks like one of its dependencies is missing.  Also, I would recommend using a newer version of Node.js.  It shouldn't matter, but v0.10.9 was a long time ago.  v0.12.0 was just released as well, if you wanted to try it.

Comment: I don´t try with v0.12.0 because on Karma installation page say: Karma works on the two latest stable versions. That is 0.8.x and 0.10.x at this point.

Comment: Anyway I will try install Karma with v.0.12.0.

Comment: That won't solve your problem though.  The issue is that `anymatch` isn't available at the version required.

Comment: Then what I have to do?

Comment: Either find a compatible version of `anymatch` manually, modify Karma to use an available version of `anymatch`, or put an issue in and hope someone else fixes it.

Comment: I put an issue on Github, but I don´t want loose my time waiting for it. What you suggest is manually install a version of anymatch and modify the dependence of Karma to use the version installed anymatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem upgrading the version of npm from  1.2.24 to 2.5.0 with the following steps:

- Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs or  C:\Program Files\nodejs, depending on the version installed with cmd.exe.
- Run the installation without -g:   `npm install npm`.
- Then run the Karma installation command: `npm install karma`.

I found the steps to upgrade npm and other common problems [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows).